# ActionLink not generating correct url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

ASP.NET MVC3/Razor

I am having problems getting the HtmlActionLink to pick the correct route (the second below).

Here are all my routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("LoginPage", "login", new { controller = "login", action = "index" });

routes.MapRoute("HomePage", "pages/{client}/{matter}", new { controller = "home", action = "index", client = UrlParameter.Optional, matter = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "default", action = "index" });
```

Here is the action link:

```
Html.ActionLink("user name", "index", "home", new RouteValueDictionary(new { client="abcdef" }), null)
```

I end up with this:

```
http://domain/home?client="abcdef"
```

Anyone know whit it is not matching the second route? Or a way to debug it

Comment: IMHO: Use `RouteLink` instead of `ActionLink`. It's faster, and it can't possibly pick the "wrong" route.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, what you pasted works for me :), meaning I got second route picked and proper link. Do you have any other routes, or only those three? I got your result when I removed matter = UrlParameter.Optional (sure you were recompiling project while you were experimenting ;-).

Comment: Problem is that matter IS optional, so if I send null it won't work.